# Reading the Akata Series out of order

Tags: nsibidi-scripts

Will it throw off the flow if the Akata series is read out of order? I’ve read Akata Witch already and bought Akata Woman, but have yet to read Akata Warrior.

*Really looking forward to devouring another Nnedi book!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would miss out on a lot. Without spoiling things, here is why.

In the first place, the whole plot of the third book of the *Nsibidi Scripts* series (*Akata Woman*) is motivated by a deal that Sunny and her friends made in the second book. Without reading *Akata Warrior*, it would be unclear why Sunny has to go on the quests that she does in the third book, although you could probably pick up most of the details.

There are a lot of references to smaller events that happened in the second book, too. Sunny's relationship with her parents and her friends, as well as with herself...in a manner of speaking...has changed due to those events, so it is best to read the second book to understand why.

In fact, I would go even further and recommend that you read *Zarah the Windseeker*, since otherwise a particular event will seem completely unexpected.

Comment: yay! thank you for the heads up, I will 